# Uploading huge files (> 2GB) to websphere

Tags: java, file, jakarta-ee, web-applications, websphere

I have a web application deployed on websphere 8.5.5, I want to upload a huge file (~3 GB) but my problem is that the **content-length** is `null` in-case the file size is more than (2GB), although when I deployed the same application on tomcat everything is working as expected.

```
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    ServletFileUpload sfu = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory());

    sfu.setSizeMax(-1);
    httpRequest.getHeader(FileUploadBase.CONTENT_LENGTH); //This returns null for huge files !
```

Comment: are you using a browser capable of handling 2+ gig files, and a webserver+os that can do the same?

Comment: yes, the same application with same browser and os working as expected when we use tomcat application-server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a small problem with WAS 8.5.5 if the content length is greater then 2GB httpRequest.getContentLength() will return -1 as expected but httpRequest.getHeader("Content-Length") will return null.

The problem is resolved with support for Servlet 3.1 which was added to the WebSphere Application Server Liberty profile 8.5.5.4 and is also resolved in the WebSphere Application Sever V9 beta available here: https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/blog/2015/10/17/websphere-application-server-v9-beta/

In 8.5.5 you could work around the issue by setting the content length as a query parameter or including it in the path info of the request. Alternatively if you have support you can contact IBM service to open an PMR and request a fix.